# Yosys interpret and and not gate as nand for visualization

Tags: yosys

I was trying to use yosys purely for visualization in combination with https://github.com/nturley/netlistsvg. A tool which takes a yosys generated json file and creates an SVG out of it. If I have the verilog code:

```
module test(a,b,c);
    input wire a,b;
    output wire c;
    assign c = ~(a & b);
endmodule
```

I want to generate an SVG file that has a NAND gate. I use the following Yosys commands:

```
read_verilog test.v
write_json output.json
```

Yosys interprests the assign statement as an AND gate and a NOT gate and outputs the following json:

```
{
  "creator": "Yosys 0.7 (git sha1 61f6811, gcc 6.2.0-11ubuntu1 -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/yosys-OIL3SR/yosys-0.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -fPIC -Os)",
  "modules": {
    "test": {
      "attributes": {
        "src": "test.v:1"
      },
      "ports": {
        "a": {
          "direction": "input",
          "bits": [ 2 ]
        },
        "b": {
          "direction": "input",
          "bits": [ 3 ]
        },
        "c": {
          "direction": "output",
          "bits": [ 4 ]
        }
      },
      "cells": {
        "$not$test.v:4$2": {
          "hide_name": 1,
          "type": "$not",
          "parameters": {
            "Y_WIDTH": 1,
            "A_WIDTH": 1,
            "A_SIGNED": 0
          },
          "attributes": {
            "src": "test.v:4"
          },
          "port_directions": {
            "Y": "output",
            "A": "input"
          },
          "connections": {
            "Y": [ 4 ],
            "A": [ 5 ]
          }
        },
        "$and$test.v:4$1": {
          "hide_name": 1,
          "type": "$and",
          "parameters": {
            "Y_WIDTH": 1,
            "B_WIDTH": 1,
            "A_WIDTH": 1,
            "B_SIGNED": 0,
            "A_SIGNED": 0
          },
          "attributes": {
            "src": "test.v:4"
          },
          "port_directions": {
            "Y": "output",
            "B": "input",
            "A": "input"
          },
          "connections": {
            "Y": [ 5 ],
            "B": [ 3 ],
            "A": [ 2 ]
          }
        }
      },
      "netnames": {
        "$not$test.v:4$2_Y": {
          "hide_name": 1,
          "bits": [ 4 ],
          "attributes": {
            "src": "test.v:4"
          }
        },
        "$and$test.v:4$1_Y": {
          "hide_name": 1,
          "bits": [ 5 ],
          "attributes": {
            "src": "test.v:4"
          }
        },
        "c": {
          "hide_name": 0,
          "bits": [ 4 ],
          "attributes": {
            "src": "test.v:3"
          }
        },
        "b": {
          "hide_name": 0,
          "bits": [ 3 ],
          "attributes": {
            "src": "test.v:2"
          }
        },
        "a": {
          "hide_name": 0,
          "bits": [ 2 ],
          "attributes": {
            "src": "test.v:2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to force yosys to interpret the line as a nand gate and output json more like this:

```
{
  "creator": "Yosys 0.7 (git sha1 61f6811, gcc 6.2.0-11ubuntu1 -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/yosys-OIL3SR/yosys-0.7=. -fstack-protector-strong -fPIC -Os)",
  "modules": {
    "test": {
      "attributes": {
        "src": "test.v:1"
      },
      "ports": {
        "a": {
          "direction": "input",
          "bits": [ 2 ]
        },
        "b": {
          "direction": "input",
          "bits": [ 3 ]
        },
        "c": {
          "direction": "output",
          "bits": [ 4 ]
        }
      },
      "cells": {
        "$nand$test.v:4$1": {
          "hide_name": 1,
          "type": "$nand",
          "parameters": {
            "Y_WIDTH": 1,
            "B_WIDTH": 1,
            "A_WIDTH": 1,
            "B_SIGNED": 0,
            "A_SIGNED": 0
          },
          "attributes": {
            "src": "test.v:4"
          },
          "port_directions": {
            "Y": "output",
            "B": "input",
            "A": "input"
          },
          "connections": {
            "Y": [ 4 ],
            "B": [ 3 ],
            "A": [ 2 ]
          }
        }
      },
      "netnames": {
        "$nand$test.v:4$1_Y": {
          "hide_name": 1,
          "bits": [ 5 ],
          "attributes": {
            "src": "test.v:4"
          }
        },
        "c": {
          "hide_name": 0,
          "bits": [ 4 ],
          "attributes": {
            "src": "test.v:3"
          }
        },
        "b": {
          "hide_name": 0,
          "bits": [ 3 ],
          "attributes": {
            "src": "test.v:2"
          }
        },
        "a": {
          "hide_name": 0,
          "bits": [ 2 ],
          "attributes": {
            "src": "test.v:2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or is this not something that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not run any kind of synthesis, the design is still in the form of a word-wide RTL netlist. In this context "$and", "$not" and similar lowercase cells are multibit cells designed to match the Verilog operators.

Running the "synth" command will synthesise your design to a standard set of single-bit gate level cells. This includes a NAND cell. Note that these cells will have uppercase names such as "$_NAND_" and are equivalent to basic logic gates.